# Где ошибка в коде?

Tags: fortran

Дан массив ненулевых целых чисел размера N. Проверить, образуют ли его элементы геометрическую прогрессию. Если образуют, то вывести знаменатель прогрессии, если нет — вывести 0.

```
program zz1
    integer,allocatable,dimension(:)::a
    integer::i,n,k=0
    print*,'Enter n'
    read*,n
    allocate(a(n))
    do i=1,n
        read*,a(i)
    end do
    do i=1,n
    if((a(i)/(a(i)-1)).eq.(a(i)+1/a(i)))then
        k=k+1
    end if
    end do
    if(k.eq.(n-2))then
        print*,'Geomtricheskaya Progressiya',(a(2)/a(1))
    end if
end program
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неправильный порядок скобок:

```
if((a(i)/(a(i)-1)).eq.(a(i)+1/a(i)))then
```

Надо бы:

```
if((a(i)/(a(i-1)).eq.(a(i+1)/a(i)))then
```

Но тогда выходит проблема с индексами и счетчик цикла надо изменить к виду:

```
do i=1,n-1
    if((a(i)/(a(i-1)).eq.(a(i+1)/a(i)))then
        k=k+1
    end if
end do
```

Comment: Вот в чем дело. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Сразу не заметил еще одной засады. Считать все-таки надо с двух до n-1.

Comment: Вы бы могли сказать, ход решения относительно задачи правилен?
Да, с do=2,n-1 это уже моя ошибка.

Comment: Большое спасибо, ichbinkubik, скомпилировал, вроде выдает решение.

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал решение навроде:
double k=a(2)/a(1)
do i=2,n-1
    if((a(i+1)/(a(i)).ne.(k))then
        print*,'Ne geometricheskaya'
        //Аварийный останов программы
    end if
end do
print*, 'Geometricheskaya: ',k